# Proxy Issues with Install Module

Tags: git, powershell, posh-git

Running the following setup:

- Server 2012 R2
- PSVersion: 4.0
- WSManStackVersion: 3.0
- Git version 2.11.1
- Package Management Preview - x64: 10.0.10586.117
- SharpZipLib: 0.86.0
- NuGet: 2.8.5.208

Trying to install the posh-git module gives:

```
PowerShellGet\Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
```

But getting

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found
>   for the specified search criteria and module name 'posh-git'.

When trying `Get-PackageSource` and `Get-PSRepository` I get

> WARNING: Unable to find package sources

and

> WARNING: Unable to find module repositories.

I'm sitting behind a TMG proxy and tried using the `-Proxy` switch and setting setting winttp proxy with no luck.

Comment: Try adding the PowerShellGallery repo manually `Register-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -SourceLocation https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/ -Proxy ... -ProxyCredential (Get-Credential)`.  If that works, make sure `Get-PSRepository` returns the newly registered repo.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that did the trick in the end.

I've since made an exception in my proxy for the machine and noticed that PowerShell 5.1 seems to be a bit easier to configure in that respect.

Comment: If you are having issue with `Register-PSRepository` returning errors, first run `Get-PSRepository`. You might find the it _is_ registered is _untrusted_, in which case you should use `Set-PsRepository`

Answer (score 2):

A per Keith Hill's suggestion, adding the PowerShellGallery repo manually worked:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -SourceLocation https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
```

I had trouble getting this working with the -proxy switch, so I set the proxy via netsh which did the trick:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="http=myproxy:8080"
```

Answer (score 2):

Proxy can be set via `-Proxy` parameter  of many network cmdlets or `$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{ "*:Proxy"="http://proxy:port" }`